How to add metadata for Token program
Maybe I need some guidance to really understand the program, I hope you will help. Thank you very much
currently i have token program and i need to add metadata , can you show me how to do it

use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use anchor_spl::{token::Mint, token_2022::Token2022};

use crate::state::InitializeTokenMetadata;

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(params: InitializeTokenMetadata)]
pub struct InitToken<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub metadata: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
    #[account(
        init,
        seeds = [b"mint", mint.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
        payer = payer,
        mint::decimals = params.decimals,
        mint::authority = mint,
    )]
    pub mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,
    pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token2022>,
}




If you're using Anchor and want to use the token-2022 metadata extension, you may want to follow the example in the Anchor repository at https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/b6724d2bcbfb5531224057c49afaa4e8c50c5137/tests/spl/token-extensions/programs/token-extensions/src/instructions.rs#L31
Copying from there and removing unneeded extensions:
#[derive(AnchorDeserialize, AnchorSerialize)]
pub struct CreateMintAccountArgs {
    pub name: String,
    pub symbol: String,
    pub uri: String,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(args: CreateMintAccountArgs)]
pub struct CreateMintAccount<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    /// CHECK: can be any account
    pub authority: Signer<'info>,
    #[account()]
    /// CHECK: can be any account
    pub receiver: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
    #[account(
        init,
        signer,
        payer = payer,
        mint::token_program = token_program,
        mint::decimals = 0,
        mint::authority = authority,
        mint::freeze_authority = authority,
        extensions::metadata_pointer::authority = authority,
        extensions::metadata_pointer::metadata_address = mint,
    )]
    pub mint: Box<InterfaceAccount<'info, Mint>>,
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = payer,
        associated_token::token_program = token_program,
        associated_token::mint = mint,
        associated_token::authority = receiver,
    )]
    pub mint_token_account: Box<InterfaceAccount<'info, TokenAccount>>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    pub associated_token_program: Program<'info, AssociatedToken>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token2022>,
}

impl<'info> CreateMintAccount<'info> {
    fn initialize_token_metadata(
        &self,
        name: String,
        symbol: String,
        uri: String,
    ) -> ProgramResult {
        let cpi_accounts = TokenMetadataInitialize {
            program_id: self.token_program.to_account_info(),
            mint: self.mint.to_account_info(),
            metadata: self.mint.to_account_info(), // metadata account is the mint, since data is stored in mint
            mint_authority: self.authority.to_account_info(),
            update_authority: self.authority.to_account_info(),
        };
        let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new(self.token_program.to_account_info(), cpi_accounts);
        token_metadata_initialize(cpi_ctx, name, symbol, uri)?;
        Ok(())
    }
}

pub fn handler(ctx: Context<CreateMintAccount>, args: CreateMintAccountArgs) -> Result<()> {
    ctx.accounts.initialize_token_metadata(
        args.name.clone(),
        args.symbol.clone(),
        args.uri.clone(),
    )?;
    ctx.accounts.mint.reload()?;
    let mint_data = &mut ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info();
    let metadata = get_mint_extensible_extension_data::<TokenMetadata>(mint_data)?;
    assert_eq!(metadata.mint, ctx.accounts.mint.key());
    assert_eq!(metadata.name, args.name);
    assert_eq!(metadata.symbol, args.symbol);
    assert_eq!(metadata.uri, args.uri);
    let metadata_pointer = get_mint_extension_data::<MetadataPointer>(mint_data)?;
    let mint_key: Option<Pubkey> = Some(ctx.accounts.mint.key());
    let authority_key: Option<Pubkey> = Some(ctx.accounts.authority.key());
    assert_eq!(
        metadata_pointer.metadata_address,
        OptionalNonZeroPubkey::try_from(mint_key)?
    );
    assert_eq!(
        metadata_pointer.authority,
        OptionalNonZeroPubkey::try_from(authority_key)?
    );
    // transfer minimum rent to mint account
    update_account_lamports_to_minimum_balance(
        ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
    )?;
    Ok(())
}


thank you so much
